# How can I force an immediate MFA prompt on any account as a domain admin

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I want to conduct an MFA fatigue test and am trying to find the best way to force an MFA auth prompt. I've been playing with a registered application in Azure that has a forced MFA grant through conditional access policy on it and some c# code using PublicClientApplicationBuilder but it never seems to MFA at all, completely ignoring the conditional access policy it would seem and silently provides me a user token every time.
`authResult = publicClientMFAApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithAccount(account).WithSystemWebViewOptions(new SystemWebViewOptions() { BrowserRedirectSuccess = new Uri("http://localhost") }).WithPrompt(Microsoft.Identity.Client.Prompt.NoPrompt).ExecuteAsync().Result;`

So I'm thinking this isn't the right direction. I'm wondering if someone could point me in another direction, I'm not married to using c#, it could be any other method (PowerShell, JS, whatever...)

Thanks

Tried PublicClientApplicationBuilder with Registered App and Conditional Access policy expecting MFA popup but none appears and token is silently issued without any prompts.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

To enable MFA for any account you can create conditional access policy.

In your ***Azure active directory*** -> **Security** ->  **Conditional Access** -> **New policy**

In Assignments -> Select all users like below:

[image]

In cloud apps or actions -> Include -> Select All cloud apps

[image]

In Access controls -> Grant -> Grant access -> Require multifactor authentication -> click ->Select.

[image]

After creating the policy, the MFA screen will pop up for any account like below:

[image]

> **Note** that, Enabling MFA for all the users will be a risk so as an emergency access, you can exclude one user while creating conditional access:

[image]

**Reference**:

[Enable MFA with PowerShell -  ALI TAJRAN](https://www.alitajran.com/enable-mfa-office-365-powershell/)

Comment: That just describes what I've already done. As I mentioned in the original post that doesn't work.  Tokens are still delivered with publicClientMFAApp.AcquireTokenInteractive regardless of this forced conditional access policy

Comment: Same issue for me